# Pig Java UDF: Generating dynamic tuple schema based on input parameters

Tags: java, apache-pig, udf

EDIT:  I'm going to try and explain in general what I want to do.

1 row of input looks like:  field1, field2, textfield

Now **textfield** is a string entry that is a fixed number of characters.  I want to parse this string to extract substrings from those characters.  So for example, I want to extract the first 10 characters and make that a field, extract the next 15 and make that a field, etc...

That part is fine.  The problem becomes not each row has the same textfield rules.  Basically **field1** and **field2** are going to represent a key for me to use to parse that text field.  This key in a map will point to an array of all of the field names I am extracting (to use in output) and also the length of each of the fields in the string (so that I can parse).

The problem I have is each of my outputs is going to be a bag with different fields and values in it.  Some rows might have a bag with 10 tuples, others with 5 or 6.  I need a way to define my schema in the exec function.

Edit:

My main goal is to be able to use my UDF input parameters to use a lookup map to derive my output schema.  I'm going to leave the rest of the post here as reference, but my main goal is to learn or find out if its possible to use input parameters to then access a map to retrieve an array of my field types.

I am trying to return a bag of tuples that each have an alias or key.  I have a map that contains an array of Strings that I need to use as alias' for the tuples.  Based on the user input into the UDF, I will fetch the correct array that contains my schema.

This is working ok in my exec function, because I have the user's input.  But I can't figure out how to also utilize that input for my output schema.

For the UDF input, the first parameter combined with the second parameter will be the key to fetch the array.  The third parameter is a large text field that I need to parse at certain character intervals, that differs for each array.

```
public class BagTupleExampleUDF extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {

TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
BagFactory mBagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();

/* Set up the number of fields for each loop/segment type */
HashMap<String, String[]> FieldsMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
Map<String,int[]> FieldsNumChar = new HashMap<String, int[]>();


@Override
public DataBag exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
    setUpMaps();


    // expect one string
    if (tuple == null || tuple.size() != 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("BagTupleExampleUDF: requires 3 input parameters.");
    }
    try {

         String param1 = (String)tuple.get(0);
         String param2 = (String)tuple.get(1);
         String textArea = (String)tuple.get(2);

         String processingText = textArea;



         String paramsCombined = loop.trim()+segment.trim();
         String[] fieldsArray = loopSegmentFieldsMap.get(paramsCombined);

         int[] endFieldsIndex = loopSegmentFieldsNumChar.get(paramsCombined);
         DataBag output = mBagFactory.newDefaultBag();

         Tuple outputTuple = mTupleFactory.newTuple();
         for(int i = 0; i < fieldsArray.length; i++){

                String temp = processingText.substring(0,endFieldsIndex[i]);
                processingText = processingText.substring(endFieldsIndex[i]);
             outputTuple.append(temp);

         }




        output.add(outputTuple);


        return output;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("BagTupleExampleUDF: caught exception processing input.", e);
    }
}
```

**Here I need some way to access that array below based on the user's input to determine which schema to use to fill out.  I have hardcoded junk in here now.  But in my for loop I need the correct array.length, and then when i set the field schema i'd be using array[i]

But i can't get access to the array in this function**

```
public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        setUpMaps();
        // Function returns a bag with this schema: { (Double), (Double) }
        // Thus the outputSchema type should be a Bag containing a Double
        try{

            Schema tupleSchema = new Schema();
            String[] test = FieldsMap.get("array1");
            for(int i = 0; i<test.length; i++){
                tupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema(test[i], DataType.CHARARRAY));

            }


            return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(getSchemaName(this.getClass().getName().toLowerCase(), input), tupleSchema, DataType.BAG));
            }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }



        public void setUpMaps(){
            FieldsMap.put("array1", new String[]{"alias1","alias2","alias3","alias4","alias5","alias6","alias7","alias8","alias9"});

            FieldsNumChar.put("array1",new int[] {6,9,4,4,30,2,5,4,11});

        }
    }
```

In reality, I will have 10+ arrays and the input will determine which array and which schema I use.  I've been stuck on this for a while now and no matter what I try I can't seem to get it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here, but AFAIK outputSchema() is only called in the frontend. So when actually executing in the backend, your maps will not be available. If you need something from the frontend invocation in the backend you can use UDFContext (http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch10.html#eval_func_constructors)

Comment: Yea I did take a look at that.  Unfortunately what I need is a way to send things from the backend to the frontend, which from what i've seen doesn't seem possible.  I've been trying to look into going a different route from using OutputSchema at all, but I haven't been able to figure out how to return a bag without it.

Comment: I've added some more information to the top of my original post.  Does that help to explain this at all?

Comment: Ok, I think I get now what you want to do. But I don't think it's possible, because as far as I get it, the schema has to be fixed after invocation of the frontend and I think you're trying to generate that dynamically depending on input.

Comment: Yea that is my understanding as well.  So what I ended up doing to handle this is I returned a Map from the exec function, which allowed me to link my key and value pairs dynamically.  So now each of my rows has a map that contains the parsed field.  Then when I group rows, I have another UDF that combines my maps.

It isn't exactly what I was hoping for, because I really wanted a way to have the map pairs to be able values in the row and have their defined schema, but I think I should be able to work with this.

Comment: If you have any tips on how to turn a Map into a bag of tuples, or values, or to just turn the map into individual fields in general with the schema defined that would be great.

Thank you for your help!